# Move Through Object List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jinja2

```
<div id="team-name">{{teams[0].name}}</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

When the "next" button is hit I would like the team-name to be the next team name in the list, i.e. 0 becomes 1?

I have a feeling I need JS to do this - but I am not sure how I would use JS to do this.

Also, the list is generated from the server.

**UPDATE**

{{ }} is part of a templating system - Jinja2 to be precise.

The teams list is passed into the webpage through Jinja2 - so the webpage has access to the entire teams list - I hope that makes sense.

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Team'
    name = db.Column(db.String(21))
    matches_total = db.Column(db.Integer())
    matches_won = db.Column(db.Integer())
    matches_lost = db.Column(db.Integer())
```

Comment: Is the `{{ }}` notation part of a templating system, or are you just indicating that you want the value in there?

Comment: {{ }} is part of a templating system - Jinja2 to be precise. Will update the question with the clarification too.

Comment: Are the other entries from the list available somewhere? If not you can't do that without server-side code.

Comment: And what does your `teams` array look like? (I'm assuming it's an array of objects, from the notation)

Comment: ^yes it's an array of objects

Comment: Updated question with extra clarifications

Answer (score 1):

Make a list containing the names available as `team_names` and update your template like this:

```
<div id="team-name" data-index="0" data-entries="{{ team_names|tojson }}">{{teams[0].name}}</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

In case you are using flask which seems to be the case, pass this to your `render_template()` call:

```
team_names=[t.name for t in Team.query]
```

Then you can use the following jQuery snippet to do what you want:

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nameElem = $('#team-name');
    var entries = nameElem.data('entries');
    var index = (nameElem.data('index') + 1) % entries.length;
    nameElem.text(entries[index]).data('index', index);
})
```

**Note: This answer assumes the list is not too big.**

Comment: Is 50 items considered too big?

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: <server.model.Team object at 0x10e97e2d0> is not JSON serializable

Comment: Read my answer carefully. You should create a list containing just the names - not `Team` objects.

Comment: Yeah, you pinpointed my exact mistake lol #signsofanawesomeprogrammer. Thanks, that did the trick, so if I want my program to update, matches_total/won/lost etc, I just do the same technique for them, right?

Comment: Then you might want to json-serialize the Team objects (simply add a method that returns the interesting values in a dict) so you don't need tons of data attributes.

Comment: Thanks so much by the way! Also, I have pictures of team logos - do you know how to do json serialization with images?

Comment: Actually I figured out how to do it - i just changed the image's src attribute to entries[index]

Comment: I've had to temporarily uncheck your answer - as it only runs once, after one move through the list, it does not move again - it goes into the function - but the entries[index] is stuck with the same value since the first time it changed. Any ideas why it only runs once?

Comment: If I look at entries - it shows all the entries, but the index never changes after the first time the function runs.

Comment: I have figured out that nameElem.data('index') is always 0 for some reason that's the problem here the new nameElem.data('index') is never saved.

Comment: Do you know how to set the new nameElem.data('index') to its value - I am getting an error when I try to do it.

Comment: Oh heh, totally forgot that in my code. Answer updated. Now it should work properly.